# How to solve situation that seems to require a setter within an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Goal {
    ...
    public boolean setParentGoal(Goal g); //should be private?? but how?
    public Goal getParentGoal();
}
```

And I feel as though having a private setter would make more sense here? since I wouldn't like anyone to be able to just "change" a Goal's parent willy nilly.

**However** when I remove it I get the following situation:

```
public boolean addSubGoal(Goal g) {
    if(g==this) return false;
    childGoals.add(g);
    g.setParentGoal(this); //compile error, cannot resolve method
    return true;
}
```

How can I resolve this situation "elegantly"?

Comment: Would you like to be able to call set or not? Or just once?

Comment: Why do u want to remove setter? You mean having setter in interface is not elegant?

Comment: you can set the variable g as private and the setter as public

Comment: i would suggest pass the parameter in constructor, instead of making setter private.

Comment: Remove the setter from the interface and include it as a protected method of a GoalImpl abstract base class from which your Goals derive or alternatively, simply as a private or package private method of your single concrete Goal implementation.

Comment: I don't want the setter to be public, I assume, because no one should need the functionality, it should only be called from within the class. However, I would have liked to be able to call from the static type goal, which is an interface.

Comment: If there's situations a parent needs to be set, you could keep the setter - but if you try to set to null or Goal already has a parent throw an Exception and document this behaviour?

Comment: @Basilevs I have provided one. May I ask why did you ask for an answer?

Comment: I don't think you have properly defined your class-structure and the associations between classes and interfaces. I would like to know more about the concrete situation to be able to offer a better and appropriate solution. In general, I would advise you to read about different design patterns (strategy, decorator, adapter, facade, template, etc.) and about associations and relations between classes and interfaces (compositions, aggregations, has-a relationships, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are not aware, all the method in a `interface` are by default `public`, so you can not make them `private`.

As you don't want anyone to change the state of your instance, I would suggest you to pass them in the `constructor` while creating the object itself. So the state of the instance can not be updated, all the others can do is, create new instance if required.

---

The `Point` class does not have any setter method for updating the state of `Point` object once created. The value of the coordinates are passed in the constructor itself.

```
public class Point {
  int x;
  int y;

  public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer. I think I know what you mean but could you or someone else perhaps provide some code as an example?

Comment: @k4kuz0 I have tried to provide you an example. I hope it will help.